# This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment

Tags: javascript, html, bots, webdriver-io, botium-box

I am doing End-to-End testing using **botium webdriverIO connector** and getting the following error:

***"...WebDriver error on UserSays: javascript error: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment."***

Did someone have such problem? How it can be fixed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems to have something to do with "trusted types" - https://web.dev/trusted-types/ - and maybe your CSP-Headers prevent it. Can you disclose the URL of the website ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error when attempting DOM manipulation via Puppeteer and JS:  this.page.setContent(contentWav);